# How can I mirror my Facebook page to my Instagram?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, instagram

Can anyone tell me how to link my Facebook ***page*** (not my profile) to my Instagram account?

I want photos I post on my FB page to mirror to my IG account.

All the instructions I can find online seem to go the other direction... that is, they all seem to be for having your IG posts show up on your FB page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that it will be easy to do so. Apparently the Instagram API doesn't allow for posting photos to your Instagram stream. (This explains why the [IFTTT Instagram channel](http://ifttt.com/instagram) has only Triggers and no Actions.)

It's trivially easy to do in the other direction, though.