# How to mirror all Facebook posts to Instagram Instagram?

Tags: facebook-pages, instagram

How to auto post to Instagram every post from a Facebook page? ****Not the other way around. Also, from a Facebook page, not directly from my Facebook account.****

So every time I post on a Facebook page, the post should also appear on my chosen Instagram account.. ****Also, I hope to find a one-time setting, not an option that I must choose for every post I make on the Facebook page.****, which is the approach mentioned in: https://www.alphr.com/how-to-automatically-post-from-facebook-to-instagram/

There are similar posts here on Webapps SE:
[How can I mirror my Facebook page to my Instagram?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75037/how-can-i-mirror-my-facebook-page-to-my-instagram)
[Automatically post to Instagram from Twitter / Facebook / Tumblr post?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103798/automatically-post-to-instagram-from-twitter-facebook-tumblr-post)
[Instagram account linked to Facebook, but cross-posting option not showing when creating Facebook Post?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134874/instagram-account-linked-to-facebook-but-cross-posting-option-not-showing-when)

But these are all very old answers.. What's the way to do it in July 2023, especially with the advent of Meta Business Suite, if relevant?

Comment: You might consider adding a bounty to the original question to attract interest for updated answers.